# Why ExposureCompensator gives black image as result?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use the `ExposureCompensator` class. I am trying to paste a small image to a bigger image but before pasting it I want to balance the brightness of two images. However when I run the code, `smallImage` will return as a black image.

PS: Also, if I use `ExposureCompensator::GAIN_BLOCK` it gives an error, Integer division by zero.

```
int num_images = 2;
int img_idx = 1;

//left and top corner position of small image
int left = 300;
int top = 400;
vector<Point> corners(num_images);
vector<Mat> images_warped(num_images);
vector<Mat> masks_warped(num_images);

images_warped.push_back(bigImage);
images_warped.push_back(smallImage);

corners.push_back(Point(0, 0));
corners.push_back(Point(left, top));

//created two white Mats as masks
Mat bigMask, smallMask;
bigMask.create(bigImage.size(), CV_8U);
bigMask.setTo(Scalar::all(255));

smallMask.create(smallImage.size(), CV_8U);
smallMask.setTo(Scalar::all(255));

masks_warped.push_back(bigMask);
masks_warped.push_back(smallMask);

int expos_comp_type = detail::ExposureCompensator::GAIN;
Ptr<detail::ExposureCompensator> compensator = detail::ExposureCompensator::createDefault(expos_comp_type);
compensator->feed(corners, images_warped, masks_warped);
compensator->apply(img_idx, corners[img_idx], smallImage, smallMask);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create vector objects in codes:

```
vector<Point> corners(num_images);
vector<Mat> images_warped(num_images);
vector<Mat> masks_warped(num_images);
```

The size of objects will be 2.
After the push_back()method ,the size will be 4.

Try to replace the codes above to:

```
vector<Point> corners(0);
vector<Mat> images_warped(0);
vector<Mat> masks_warped(0);
```